# error : LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C"

Tags: c++, mfc

What's wrong with this unresolved externals? I'm trying to implement this into `InitInstance` of my MFC application. But I'm getting this line error from the debugger.

```
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __stdcall EnumProcesses(unsigned long *,unsigned long,unsigned long *)" (?EnumProcesses@@$$J212YGHPAKK0@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall COkApp::InitInstance(void)" (?InitInstance@COpenEyeProcessApp@@$$FUAEHXZ)
```

Here is the `OkApp` files :

**OkApp.h**

```
//...
#include <psapi.h>
//...
```

**OkApp.cpp**

```
#include "OkApp.h"
//...
BOOL COkApp::InitInstance()
{
    //...
    if (!EnumProcesses(aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    //...
}
```

Knowing that my project is coded into `Unicode project`, how do I to fix this, please?

Any brilliant idea, please?

Comment: Did you link with the Psapi.lib library ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz, No how to deal that, please?

Comment: In the project properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies add psapi.lib, or do as suggested in CodeDreamer's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Psapi.lib to be linked.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Psapi.lib")
```

Comment: in the `.cpp` file or the `.h` file? Do I need to remove the `#include <psapi.h>`line, please?

Comment: Just input in your .cpp, below #include <psapi.h>.

Comment: What does `#pragma comment` mean, please?

Comment: `#pragma comment` can be used in many ways. In this case, it's used for linking library.

Comment: But, what's the difference between `#include` and `#pragma comment`?

Comment: For using *.lib, you have to include *.h file and link to the *.lib. Please read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us/library/ms235627.aspx) article.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `EnumProcesses` is declared `extern "C"` in the header, but not in the source file. Both have to be consistent. Either change both to `extern "C"` (if you intend to use `EnumProcesses` from within C), or remove the `extern "C"` in the header.

EDIT: Or you just forgot to add the library containing `EnumProcesses` when calling the linker.

Comment: can you more detail this please?

Comment: First you should give more detail. Is `EnumProcesses` part of something you have written yourself, or part of an API that you want to use?

Comment: it's part from `#include <psapi.h>`.

Comment: Then it's the part after "EDIT" that's wrong. But it seems you already solved it with CodeDreamers' help.